# Resharper live templates - inn & ifn

Tags: resharper

Do I have something similiar to intelij's "ifn" and "inn" live template in ReSharper?
("if not null" and "if null" templates )
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

ReSharper doesn't have these built in, but you can easily write them yourself.
Just go to *ReSharper > Templates Explorer... > Surround Templates* and add a new template with something like this:

```
if ($SELECTION$ == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("$SELECTION$");
}
```

Then you can select something and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd> to surround the selection with your template:

[image: Surround with selector]

In my case, I added it to the *quicklist* with the letter *F*.

If you want to be able to type `ifn` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you need to add a *Live Template*. This can be done in the *Template Explorer*, under *Live Templates*, but the content has to be different:

```
if ($ARGUMENT$ == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("$ARGUMENT$");
}
```

or maybe:

```
if ($ARGUMENT$ == null)
{
    $END$
}
```

Then you can write `ifn` (if that was the shortcut you specified) and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: and adding them to the ctrl+j screen? as with foreach?

Comment: I did as described (live templates) and when I press inn 
it types "Argument" and not the argument itself

Comment: var car = getCar();                                                       if (ARGUMENT == null)
{

}

Comment: So you want ReSharper to *GUESS* which variable you want to check? You could set the macro for `$ARGUMENT$` to something like *Execute smart completion*...

Comment: guess. yess. it does that in intellij and in other templates. I have chosen the regular "Suggest Name for variable" for argument macro value. but it does not fill it.

Comment: usualy it should suggest the last variable declared